# How does Motormaster's height compare to Menasor's?

Tags: transformers

In other combiners like Devastator, members form their limbs by attaching themselves to the torso. However in the case of Menasor, the Stunticons cars simply attach to the sides of Motormaster limbs. This would mean Menasor's height should be about the same than Motormaster's, unless some "magic" or size changing happens (something that couldnt be solved in collection toys I guess)

How does MotorMaster's height compare to Menasor's? Is he supposed to be almost as tall as Menasor, or is he supposed to be as tall as a regular Decepticon or a tall Decepticon, but far from Menasor's height?

Comment: *Unlike Optimus' Prime, Motormaster's original robot mode design is formed from both his truck cab and trailer, although in most depictions he is depicted as still being **similar in height to Optimus** regardless* - https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Motormaster_(G1)

Comment: 'unless some "magic" or size changing happens' — like when Megatron somehow shrinks down to become a pistol that Starscream can hold in his hand.

Comment: @Valorum sounds like an answer

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I know, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @Pablo - It sounds like half of an (uncited) answer

Answer (score 0):

if you watch the g1 cartoon Motormaster is shown to visually shrink down in robot mode and his cab compacts to form his feet there is a third party masterpiece size Motormaster with very interesting engineering that compacts and folds his trailer on to his back. in truck trailer mode his size and length is roughly the size of mp 10 optimus Prime with his trailer. and only slightly taller in robot mode than MP 10. motor master robot mode is now roughly half the size of his truck mode. and in combined mode utilizes the whole trailer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You could improve your answer by adding some pictures that show the comparisons you're making.